# How can I preview a device in landscape mode in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

How can I preview a device in landscape mode in SwiftUI?

I just have a simple preview like this:

```
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good a question! I tried adding `.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass,.compact)` and `.environment(\.verticalSizeClass, .compact)` to a iPhone SE preview, but doesn't rotate.

Comment: are you asking about storyboard?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry no, this is SwiftUI.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## Xcode 13

Now you can preview in landscape mode with `.previewInterfaceOrientation` modifier to make it `landscapeLeft` or `landscapeRight`.

<sub>⚠️  The following image from WWDC21 uses `horizontal` and `vertical` that is **NOT** available in Xcode 13 beta!</sub>

[image]

---

## Old but not Useless method:

You can set the size to any landscape size you want for `PreviewProvider`:

```
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
           .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 1024, height: 768))
           // iPad Mini landscape size
    }
}
```

This is `iPad Mini` landscape mode size.

**Update**: Xcode detects the device associated to the preview from the selected simulator at the top left of the IDE and it and will apply the safe area as you expected for some iPads and iPhones landscape mode.

## Master-Detail Demo

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Master")
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Also, you can play with these two modifiers as your needs:

```
    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
    .environment(\.verticalSizeClass, .compact)
```

Comment: Thanks. Best answer before Apple releases landscape mode.

Comment: Hope Apple will releases landscape mode asap

Comment: I disagree; the best answer _today_ is that it can't be done. The fixed size won't respect safe areas (as mentioned), but also doesn't resize ancillary chrome, such as status, navigation and tab bars. Finally, on iPad it won't show master/detail views properly.

Comment: now it's supporting safe area **AND** show master/detail as you can see in the demo @SteveMadsen and other +20 :)

Comment: This hack does not work for _live_ previews.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini The `.previewInterfaceOrientation` is now available in the RC.

Answer (score 5):

### iOS 15+ / Xcode 13+

Starting from iOS 15 we can use [`previewInterfaceOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyhstack/previewinterfaceorientation(_:)):

```
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeRight)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ContentView().previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width:568,height:320))
```

[View - IOS screen dimensions for different devices](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

Answer (score 2):

## XCode 15, iOS 17, #Preview macros

> https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10252/

```swift
#Preview(traits: . landscapeLeft) { // <- use traits instead
    ContentView()
        //.previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft) // <- no longer supported
}
```

Comment: Says `traits: . landscapeLeft` requires iOS 17. If we still support iOS 16 etc in our app, we probably need to continue using `struct Blabla_Previews: PreviewProvider` and `.previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeRight)` etc.

Comment: @Jonny Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the highlight description.

Comment: We can add `@available(iOS 17.0, *)` before and it will work in previews even if we also support older iOS versions:
`@available(iOS 17.0, *)
#Preview(traits: .landscapeLeft) {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "hi"
    return label
}`

Comment: Hm, are you sure about this? I think it will not work. I tried. Apple staff also mentions it [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731865).

Comment: Yes it compiles for me