# Did previewInterfaceOrientation() stop working in Xcode 15?

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

I was looking for how to change the orientation of the preview in Xcode 15 and found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625931/how-can-i-preview-a-device-in-landscape-mode-in-swiftui), however this is not working for me (I'm using 15.0.1 - 15A507). Has this changed in Xcode 15? Is there another method to change the preview orientation to landscape?

My preview code looks like:

```
#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
}
```

and this is not producing any change to the preview orientation in Xcode 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was changed to `traits`, try this:

```swift
#Preview(traits: . landscapeLeft) {
    ContentView()
        //.previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
}
```